# Nikon D610 problems with over and under exposure

Tags: exposure

lately, when I shoot with my Nikon D610 (on a tripod, inside with a non moving subject) I get the following. First shot, severely overexposed, second shot severely underexposed and the third shot is correct. 
Any thoughts

Comment: Sounds like its making its own HDR (High Dynamic Range) image sequence.

Comment: Turn off automatic exposure bracketing!

Answer (score 5):

Check if you activated bracketing.

(Button on the left below flash button. Menu e6. [Manual](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18706/~/users-manual---d610))